# changing culture for a winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, culture

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209133/exception-messages-in-english/448549#448549) I have built a sample console application in which I change the culture in the Main function. It works well.

Now, building another sample **winform** application, I wonder where would be the best place to put this

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture ("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture=new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

If I put this in the constructor of a Form1, will this apply to all operations in this class?

What if this Form1 opens another form Form2 and an exception occurs there?

What if Form1 uses another class Class1?

I am willing to experiment in this, but if someone has an answer based on previous knowledge, I appreciate to hear it.

Comment: You're setting `CultureInfo` to the thread so every object bound to that thread ( created in it's context ) will use the same `CultureInfo`

Answer (score 2):

For a *winforms application* put things that deal with the context of the entire application in program.cs and be done with it.

> - If I put this in the constructor of a Form1, will this apply to all operations in this class?
> - What if this Form1 opens another form Form2 and an exception occurs there?
> - What if Form1 uses another class Class1?

All your other concerns are irrelevant, and are sereverly overthinking the problem.

***Note*** : The best way to learn programming windows or any other language is to read as much as you can. Microsoft have everything documented always go straight to the source.

**Some additional reading for you**

[Thread.CurrentUICulture Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Thread.CurrentCulture Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Initialization code in a WinForms App - Program.cs or MainForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221113/initialization-code-in-a-winforms-app-program-cs-or-mainform)